# How can I pass a string as parameter? using System.Net.Http;

Tags: c#, visual-studio, post, system.net.httpwebrequest

I am using this line

```
client.PostAsync("mysite.net/login.asmx/login", content);
```

And I need that my content be something like **id=21&name=myname&password=pass&json=1** 
It should be a string
but the accepted type here is a **FormUrlEncodedContent** and because of that I don't know how this class create the value, if it works like a json or not and if it will change this structure **id=21&name=myname&password=pass&json=1** that I need (it should be the rest of the url)
How can I send it and receive the response converting it to my class **user**, for example?

I am using it as well

```
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                    {
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("id", "125"),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("mailadress", login),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", pass),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("json", "1"),
                     });
```

How my webservice will receive it? how this class(above) organize the key-value?

my class

```
class User
{
    public string codigo { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string senha { get; set; }
    public string imagem { get; set; }
    public DateTime dataDeNasc { get; set;}
    public string cidade { get; set; }
    public string estado { get; set; }
    public string telefone { get; set; }
    public string sexo { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you very much.
I really need this help

Comment: `receive the response converting it to my class user` Please include the source code for **user**.

Comment: I will, wait....

Comment: @mjwills How can I do?? could you help?

Answer (score 1):

The sending of the body will be exactly like in the Form URL Encoded (similar to your example string), in your C# example it will be sent as:

```
id=125&mailaddress=login&password=pass&json=1
```